# Tool/Plugin/JS to work out how an elements layout(height/width/position) has been determined

Tags: html, css, positioning

Can the DOM be walked to report on what has caused an element to be sized and positioned?

I have a issue that probably could easily be solved if could browse the 'chain' of influences on the element.

Answer (score 0):

Walking an element's `offsetParent` repeatedly can help you find out what parent elements cause the element's position to be as it is currently. I don't know about finding the size influence, though.